# Can't get authorized in python

Tags: python, http, authentication

I have tried both following ways found here and neither worked for me.

```
# create a password manager
password_mgr = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
password_mgr.add_password(None, top_level_url, user, passwd)

handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_mgr)

# create "opener" (OpenerDirector instance)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(handler)

# use the opener to fetch a URL
opener.open(a_url)

# Install the opener.
# Now all calls to urllib2.urlopen use our opener.
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
```

and

```
request = urllib2.Request(temp)
# You need the replace to handle encodestring adding a trailing newline 
# (https://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html#base64.encodestring)
base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (user, passwd)).replace('\n', '')
#print base64string
request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)   
request.add_header('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')   
f = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

I can retrieve the link

```
http://www.cd-pa.com/bbs/?2880
```

but no way to get it work on

```
http://www.cd-pa.com/bbs/home.php?mod=space&uid=14476&do=album&id=6571'
```

Anyone can shed some light? Thank you.

Comment: What error do you get with the second link?

Comment: oops, somehow my correction was not in the post. The link I posted  'http://www.cd-pa.com/bbs/home.php?mod=space&uid=14476&do=album&id=6571' doesn't need authorization. It's open accessible. But the link 'http://www.cd-pa.com/bbs/home.php?mod=space&uid=23973&do=album&id=10698' doesn't work.

Comment: It's something like privacy control. The link points to the album of a user. While in a browser logged in with credentials, it's accessible. From within python, the content returned says "you can't access the data because of privacy setting"

Comment: So I take that as a 403 in HTTP status code?

Comment: Thanks Woozyking. Not sure if I understand you correctly. Or please tell me how to check the return code. As I tried, the result from urlopen is a good page, just not the content I want with a successful login. The content in the page says one is not authorized to access the data.

Comment: I see. I think urllib2 raises an HTTPError in the event of status that's not in the range of 2xx and 3xx, so clearly cd-pa.com returns 200 regardless of auth error. I would suggest replicate this process and see if you can get it working using `curl` or `wget`. Are you sure it's HTTP Basic not HTTP Digest?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

> base64.b64encode("{username}:{password}".format(username,password))

for generating base64string

Comment: Thanks Andriy. It's the same. The result is the same as my version.